# drive browser from custom cucumber formatter

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber, watir

I am trying to create a custom cucumber formatter that will do something before each step. My problem is random popup banners(modals) that happen on our stage environment. I can't turn them off because marketing is testing them, and they break the regression script. Its hard to code around them because I dont know what paper they will popup or how long they will stay there. So I though creating a formatter that runs before each step. But Im having issues passing commands to the browser from it.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

module Custom
  class Formator
    def initialize(step_mother, io, options)
      @step_mother = step_mother
      @io = io
    end

    def before_step(step)
     @browser.goto "http://stage.website.local/"
    end
 end
end
```

When I use this, I am getting an error

```
undefined method `goto' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0):

i have some problems understanding your question. you are talking about a "custom cucumber formatter" but have a class called `Formator`. and that formatter is a subclass of `Watir::Browser`. how does that make sense?

from what i understand you want to do some regression testing on your staging environment. the popups break the test as they show up randomly and you don't want to disable them so testers have them.

i would suggest that you don't show those popups based on a user-agent. you can configure your test-suite to run with a specific user-agent or some other header info and disable the popups with this secret setting.